# How to get the ASP.NET temporary directory programmatically?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, cassini, temporary-files

The temporary directory that's used by ASP.NET is usually located under

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
```

Sometimes however it is overridden by the tempDirectory attribute on the compilation element in the web.config file.

How can I get the temporary directory currently used by ASP.NET regardless if it's the default directory or a user overridden directory?

P.S. There are a few properties that will return a subdirectory under the temporary directory (e.g. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DynamicDirectory` and others) but I'm looking for the directory as it appears in the configuration file.

Comment: Why and when would you want to know the ASP.NET temporary directory?

Comment: To store files in a per-site temporary folder. (each site has its own temporary folder)

Answer (score 4):

You want the static property `HttpRuntime.CodegenDir`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server" language="C#">
  void Page_Load(object Sender,EventArgs E)
  {

    lblCodegenDir.Text = System.Web.HttpRuntime.CodegenDir;
  }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Test Application</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <FORM id="frmForm1" method="post" runat="server">
      <HR width="100%" size="1">
      <P>
         ASP.Net Temp Dir:&nbsp;
        <ASP:LABEL id="lblCodegenDir" runat="server">Label</ASP:LABEL>
      </P>
      <HR width="100%" size="1">
    </FORM>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: This does not return the directory defined in the configuration file, but a dynamic sub-directory.

Comment: Hmm - Not sure what you're hunting for then.  If its the directory in the machine.config, you'd have to parse that file...